# Bash script for snoop and rotate

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that runs `snoop` interface; when the file is equal to 1 MB, it rotates the file and repeats.

```sh
snoop -d nxge4 -o /zones/as012ivr/root/NAS/log/capture.snoop  port 5060 &
pid=$(ps -ef|grep snoop |grep nobody|awk '{print $2}');
echo $pid;
while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null;
do
    size=$(ls -la /zones/as012ivr/root/NAS/log/capture.snoop | awk '{print $5}');
    if [ $size -ge 1048576 ];
    then
        kill -9 $pid;
        time=$(/usr/bin/truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 |  nawk -F= '/^time\(\)/ {gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}');
        mv /zones/as012ivr/root/NAS/log/capture.snoop /zones/as012ivr/root/NAS  /log/capture.$time.snoop;
        ./script.sh;
        break
    fi
done
```

The script doesn't work.  The snoop doesn't stop when the file `capture.snoop` is 1 MiB.

Can you help me?

O.S. Solaris 10

edit: @Jonathan Leffler
  i dont know $!...how can use?
 i have try the pid and it's correct.
 how can kill the process? whitout -9
 the script dont enter in the while part....

Comment: Why not use `$!` to get the PID of the process just launched in background?  Or does `snoop` itself fork, in which case why do you need to use the `&`.  However, that's somewhat tangential to the main issue — probably.  What have you done to debug the code?  Have you verified that the PID you get is the correct PID?  Have you run the `kill` command without redirecting errors to `/dev/null`?  Using `kill -9` is brutal — you should at least try giving the process a gentler signal (maybe 15 SIGTERM or 1 SIGHUP) first so it can leave its affairs in order.

Comment: You appear to have a single quote mark after `$5}`. Could you check that you copy-pasted correctly? Otherwise, that'll probably your problem (though it probably leads to some syntax error).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you've now added a quote mark that wasn't there before. If the OP originally copy-pasted correctly, that would hide a problem. Don't assume trivial typo's.

Comment: Running `./script.sh` is a bad idea — it gives you a new process each time you switch logs.  If you must run the script again, use `exec ./script.sh` (assuming the the relative pathname is OK — it wouldn't be the way I did it).  That means the process starts a new shell.  Or simply put a `while true; do …; done` wrapper around the whole script.

Comment: There is also something very odd about that `mv` command. Its second argument is a directory, while its last argument is a non-existent file; that should produce an error message and not move anything. The documentation I found for `snoop` does not say that `-o file` appends to `file` (rather than overwriting it) so I suppose this is not relevant to the question. But it still needs to be fixed, I think.

Comment: Also, don't you think it would be a good idea to add a bit of a sleep to that while loop? Alternatively, you might want to check out the Apache project's [`rotatelogs` utility](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html), which avoids having to kill the log-generator in order to rotate logs (pipe into `rotatelogs` and let it deal with the rotation).

Comment: _The snoop doesn't stop_ - what do you mean by that, and how do you observe it?